# preg_match doesn't include a value for final optional match

Tags: php

Maybe I'm not doing this right : I wrote this, waiting to have optional matches in my regex.

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)([A-Z]+)?-(\d+)?([A-Z]+)?$/i', $groupe, $matches);
list($match, $debutChiffre, $debutLettre, $finChiffre, $finLettre) = $matches;
```

So the matches 2, 3 and 4 are optionals. If 2 is empty but 3 isn't, 2 will be an empty array. But is the last optional is empty, there is no `$matches[4]`. If both 3 and 4 are empty, then it stops at `$matches[2]`. I would have prefered to have an empty string for each parenthesis, as after that `list()` returns a Notice each time `$matches[4]` doesn't exist and therefore it tries to put an inexistent value into `$finLettre`.

To remove those notices, is there a better way than having to add this before `list()` ?

```
if (!isset($matches[4])) $matches[4] = "";
```

Edit: I though the regex would be enough, but if examples are needed :

`5A-9B` will give a `$matches` array with 5 elements (the full match and the 4 parenthesis).

`5-9B` will give a `$matches` array with 5 elements (`$matches[2]` is an empty string as there is no letter)

`5A-9` will give a `$matches` array with 4 elements (`preg_match` ignores the last unmatched parenthesis, while it put empty string if there is at least one matched term after to be consistent with the parenthesis order)

`5-` will give a `$matches` array with 2 elements.

Because of this behavior, the next `list()` get unsetted variables and raises notices because of this.

Comment: It might help if you give us some examples of what you are trying to match,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `$matches` to array with default values. So if the match is hit, it will replace the default value:

```
<?php
preg_match('/^(\d+)([A-Z]+)?-(\d+)?([A-Z]+)?$/i', $groupe, $matches);
$matches = $matches + [[], '', '', '', ''];
list($match, $debutChiffre, $debutLettre, $finChiffre, $finLettre) = $matches;
```

This way you can have code without warnings :)